# To (lessen, improve, alleviate) Disadvantage

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

I'am looking for a genuine phrase with the word "disadvantage" in this way:

> The new method allows to (lessen? overcome? improve? - what?) the
> disadvantages of the old one.

In a meaning that the new method has less disadvantages than the old method (it does not eliminates them, but lessens? them).

I do not need the a phrase "has less disadvantages", I need a phrase as mentioned in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

*reduces the number of disadvantages* works. You can also simply go with:

> the new method is an improved version of the old one.

Your solution of *overcome* may work, but some people may view it as solving *all* the disadvantages, when you're actually reducing them. *reduces* is also a viable option.